# Image from 2 different folders to display in one table tada

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have images from 2 different folders that I want to display in a table data. I did this but it says ' missing start tag.. how do u get images in 2 folders to get in a tabledata??

```
<td><img src="../EventImages/Events/<%#Eval("images") %>" 
                <img src="../ProductImg/<%#Eval("images") %>" height="100" width="100" /></td>
```

INITIAL full code

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Full Detail</div> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="r1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
           <table class="table">
               <thead>
               <tr>
                   <td>image</td>
                   <td>name</td>
                   <td>price</td>
                   <td>quantity</td>
               </tr>
                   </thead>
               <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td><img src="../EventImages/Events/<%#Eval("images") %>" 
                 height="100" width="100" /></td>
            <td><%#Eval("name") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("price") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("qty") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    <asp:Label ID="l1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: In the first code snippet you are not closing the first image tag. `<img src="../EventImages/Events/<%#Eval("images") %>" />` this is how it should be.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to close the HTML tag. If you want 2 or more images to be displayed, you need to use a separate tag for each one.

So I suggest making another loop internally to display the images in each index.

```
<td>
    <% foreach(var image in Eval("images")){ %>
        <img src="../EventImages/Events/<%=image%>" height="100" width="100" />
    <% } %>
</td>
```

I probably wrote the function calling wrong, so let me know how to fix it and I'll edit the answer later.

Comment: I'm trying to get only 1 image to show in the table data from 2 different folders!! When I run your code it says foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object bc object does not contain a public definition for getenumerator